# Editing data that you got from a JPA query directly

Tags: java, jpa

I have a Presentation class:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

package entity;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.util.List;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Presentation") 
public class Presentation implements Serializable
{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "start_time")
    private Timestamp startTime;

    @Column(name = "end_time")
    private Timestamp endTime;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Location.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Location location;

    @ManyToMany
    private List<User> users;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "presentations")
    private List<Planning> plannings;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Timestamp getEndTime() {
        return endTime;
    }

    public void setEndTime(Timestamp endTime) {
        this.endTime = endTime;
    }

    public Location getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(Location location) {
        this.location = location;
    }

    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(List<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    public List<Planning> getPlannings() {
        return plannings;
    }

    public void setPlannings(List<Planning> plannings) {
        this.plannings = plannings;
    }

    public Timestamp getStartTime() {
        return startTime;
    }

    public void setStartTime(Timestamp startTime) {
        this.startTime = startTime;
    }
}
```

Now i can fetch these with the following query:

```
Query q = session.createQuery("SELECT p FROM " + Presentation.class.getSimpleName() + " p");
```

to get a List.

Now i need to pass something to a library that i use for showing presentations on a timeline. I would like to somehow edit this structure directly after i fetched it to match with the library api.

```
public PresentationModified(JaretDate date, int h, int m, double durH, String text) {
    JaretDate begin = date.copy().setTime(h, m, 0);
    setRealBegin(begin);

    JaretDate end = begin.copy().advanceHours(durH);
    setRealEnd(end);

    _text = text;
    checkSpanMultiple();
    changed();
}
```

I can't find a good way to fetch the query and create the corresponding objects directly afterwards.

Comment: What's the difficulty? Looping through the list? Creating a JaretDate from what you have in the presentation? What?

Comment: Well, i don't really know on how to make this with a good structure, it has to fetch the query first, and it should then pass it to a modifier of some sort. like you have these Model bindings but then this is something reversed?

Comment: You'll have to write some code: a loop which transforms each Presentation into a PresentationModified. No magical API will do it for you.

Comment: i thought there was some kind of structural layout for it